# How to run my bash functions in terminal using a parent name?

Tags: bash

* the wording of the question is terrible, sorry!

I have some bash functions I create

```
test() {echo "hello wold"}
test2() {echo "hello wold"}
```

Then in my `.bashrc` I source the file that has the above function `. ~/my_bash_scripts/testFile`

In the terminal I can run `test` and get `hello world`.

is there a way for me to add parent variable that holds all my functions together. For example `personal test`, `personal test2`.

Similar to every other gem out there, I downloaded a tweeter one. All it's methods are followed by the letter `t`, as in `t status` to write a status, instead of just `status`

Comment: Don't use `test` as a function name. `test` is a bash built-in. & this would possibly cause failures in further scripts.

Comment: Look at what you have downloaded, perhaps the answer is there.

Comment: @anishsane I didn't know but that  makes my point stronger. If I run `test` it would fail. So is there a way to say `my test`. So start my tests with a unique name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are asking about writing a command-line program. Just a simple one here:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

if [[ $# -eq 0 ]]; then
  echo "no command specified"
  exit
elif [[ $# -gt 1 ]]; then
  echo "only one argument expected"
  exit
fi

case "$1" in
  test)
    echo "hello, this is test1"
    ;;
  test2)
    echo "hello, this is test2"
    ;;
  *)
    echo "unknown command: $1"
    ;;
esac
```

Then save it and make it an executable by run `chmod +x script.sh`, and in your `.bashrc` file, add `alias personal="/fullpath/to/the/script.sh"`.

This is just very basic and simple example using `bash` and of course you can use any language you like, e.g. Python, Ruby, Node e.t.c.

Answer (score 0):

Use arguments to determine final outputs.

You can use "$#" for number of arguments.
For example,

```
if [ $# -ne 2 ]; then
    # TODO: print usage
    exit 1
fi
```

Above code exits if arguments not euqal to 2.

So below bash program

```
echo $#
```

with

```
thatscript foo bar baz quux
```

will output 4.

Finally you can combine words to determine what to put stdout.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to flag some functions as your personal functions; no, there is no explicit way to do that, and essentially, all shell functions belong to yourself (although some may be defined by your distro maintainer or system administrator as system-wide defaults).

What you *could* do is collect the output from `declare -F` at the very top of your personal shell startup file; any function not in that list is your personal function.

```
 SYSFNS=$(declare -F | awk '{ a[++i] = $3 }
    END { for (n=1; n<=i; n++) printf "%s%s", (n>1? ":" : ""), a[n] }')
```

This generates a variable `SYSFNS` which contains a colon-separated list of system-declared functions.

With that defined, you can check out which functions are yours:

```
myfns () {
    local fun
    declare -F |
    while read -r _ _ fun; do
        case :$SYSFNS: in *:"$fun":*) continue;; esac
        echo "$fun"
    done
}
```